# Match values from array with values from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two different arrays with the following format:

```
$customersList = Array(
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'JOHN LEGEND'),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'MARIAH CAREY'),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'JAY Z'),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => null),
);
$searchingValue = Array(
   Array('lastName' => 'TRAVOLTA', 'firstName' => 'JOHN'),
   Array('lastName' => 'CAREY', 'firstName' => 'MARIAH'),
   Array('lastName' => 'MODE', 'firstName' => 'DEPECHE'),
   Array('lastName' => 'BRUCE', 'firstName' => 'WILL'),
);
```

I want to match values from `$customersList` with values from `$searchingValue` based on the following algorithm: if ((firstName1 == $firstName 2 and $lastName1==$lastName2) or (firstName1 == lastName2 or lastName1 == firstName2) is true then do nothing else insert the new customer in `$customersList`.

My code is this:

```
$ignoreIfFound = true;
foreach ($searchingValue as $value) {
$uploadedAlready = false;
foreach ($customersList as $info) {
    if ($info['id'] === null and $info['title']) {
        list($paxLastName, $paxFirstName) = explode(' ', $info['title']);
        if (($paxLastName == $value['lastName'] and $paxFirstName == $value['firstName']) or ($paxLastName == $value['firstName'] and $paxFirstName == $value['lastName'])) {
         if (!$ignoreIfFound and !$uploadedAlready) {
            $customersList[] = Array('id' => null, 'title' => $value['lastName'].' '.$value['firstName']);
            $uploadedAlready = true;

            }
        }
        else {
            if (!$uploadedAlready) {
                $customersList[] = Array('id' => null, 'title' =>$value['lastName'].' '.$value['firstName']);
                $uploadedAlready = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!$uploadedAlready) {
            $customersList[] = Array('id' => null, 'title' => $value['lastName'].' '.$value['firstName']);
            $uploadedAlready = true;

        }
    }
}}
```

But it is not working properly. For given example the new customersList should be:

```
$customersList = Array(
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'JOHN LEGEND'),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'MARIAH CAREY'),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'JAY Z'),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => null),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'TRAVOLTA JOHN'),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'MODE DEPECHE'),
   Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'BRUCE WILL'),
);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this should be easier by using a database

Comment: Which kind of output do you get?

Comment: My output for $ignoreIfFound= true: is an array with all values from searchingValue appended on customersList which is not ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an Map of all already founded Keys (Firstname, Lastname and First+Lastname) and check against:

```
<?php
$alreadyInList = array ();

foreach ( $customersList as $customer) {
    $alreadyInList[$customer["title"]] = true;
    $firstLastname = explode(" ", $customer["title"]);
    $alreadyInList[$firstLastname[0]] = true;
    $alreadyInList[$firstLastname[1]] = true;
}

foreach($searchingValue as $search) {
    if (array_key_exists($alreadyInList, $search["lastname"]))
        continue;
    if (array_key_exists($alreadyInList, $search["firstname"]))
        continue;
    if (array_key_exists($alreadyInList, $search["firstname"] . " " . $search["lastname"]))
        continue;

    $customersList[] = new array() // ... insert

    $alreadyInList[$search["firstname"] . " " . $search["lastname"]] = true;
    $alreadyInList[$search["lastname"]] = true;
    $alreadyInList[$search["firstname"]] = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i rewrite this code with the requested algorithm :)